# Регулярное выражение для хештега и ссылки

Tags: twitter, регулярные-выражения, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярное выражение для поиска хештегов и ссылок в тексте.

Имеем такой текст

```
http://t.co/Z2ksh5TO6 #hastag1 Provides customized development of applications and analytics http://t.co/t8W6Js3Wa
```

Я хочу очистить его от ссылок и тегов, оставить только текст.

Помогите хотя бы с чем-то одним, а второй я уже по примеру соображу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такое регулярное выражение вполне справляется с данной задачей

```
/((http|#)([^\s]*) )|((http|#)([^\s]*)$)/Ui
```

Comment: В Вашем выражении небольшая ошибка, `\s` включает в себя табы и переносы строк, если после хэштэга или ссылки будет стоять перенос строки, то выражение не сработает. Можно было бы сделать так `[^\s]*\s`, но и это излишне. Достаточно применить жадный квантификатор, и тогда отпадет необходимость проверять что стоит после текста.  
Помимо этого лучше полностью указать протокол и учесть, что это должно быть началом слова, а не серединой.  В итоге приходим к выражению:  

    /(\bhttps?:\/\/|#)[^\s]*+/iu

Comment: Возможно я малость и ошибся (не сильно силён в RegExp)..  Но на приведённом примере строки моё выражение работало корректно

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $s = 'http://t.co/Z2ksh5TO6 #hastag1 Provides customized development of applications and analytics http://t.co/t8W6Js3Wa';
print "$1\n" if $s =~ /(#.*)$/;
#
# #hastag1 Provides customized development of applications and analytics http://t.co/t8W6Js3Wa
#
print "$1\n" if $s =~ /#\S+\s+(.*)$/;
#
# Provides customized development of applications and analytics http://t.co/t8W6Js3Wa
# 
print "$1\n" if $s =~ /#\S+\s+(.*?)\s+http:\/\/.*$/;
#
# Provides customized development of applications and analytics
#
```

Comment: ох, черт  
совсем из головы вылетело.. на php  
  
но спасибо, буду с этим разбираться

Comment: Регулярные выражения те же и в PHP будут.